# How to add new lines inline in React/JS

Tags: reactjs

I cant find a way of adding a new line in React/JS

typically I would use /n but this dosnt seem to work within my knowledge of React.

im trying to add a line between the project owner and the project description

[image: 1]

```
<StackCard imgsrc={img1}  projectOwner="Owner: Jeoffrey Baratheon"  projectDescription="Description: xxxxxx" cardtitle="Search Stack test 1" title="xxxxx" content={"Test12"}>
       
</StackCard>
```

Comment: You would have to modify `StackCard` component and add a `<br>` or `{'\n'}` character between `projectOwner` and `projectDescription`.

Comment: Please show the code for `StackCard`

Comment: `\n` is normally not used in HTML since we have `<br>` or `<p>` to create the document structure.

Comment: `<br/>` (in HTML it would be `<br>`) but in JSX they expect closing tags for all elements so `<br/>`. It will end the current line.

Comment: Depeneds what you do inside `StackCard`. If you wrap each part in a `div` or any block element or if you add `<br/>` after each property you print, it would work. Also the `\n` would never work inside html, unless you used a `pre` element.

Comment: @kkmonlee Many thanks worked spot on :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `<br/>` tag inside your StackCard component, between your render from owner and description